# In Magento-2 how to edit order summary labels with values and addon more labels there in cart page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento2, magento2.2

I want to add some labels in order summary box on cart page in magento2. Right now I got only the subtotal and tax in the order summary from default magento2 behavior, see the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1ggnt4j

I want to add and display labels with values like all these see the screenshot for reference: https://prnt.sc/1ggna7r

dummy code e.g.,

```html
<div class="cart-summary" role="tablist" style="top: 0px;"><strong class="summary title">Summary</strong></div>
<div class="table-wrapper" data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading">
    <table class="data table totals">
        <tbody><tr><td>Price on Mrp</td><!---Want to show regular price -->
</tr><tr><td><?= _$regularprice; ?></td><!---regular price value -->
</tr><tr><td>Discount on MRP</td><!---Want to show discount amount-->
</tr><tr><td><?= _$discountamount; ?></td><!---discount price amount value-->
</tr><tr><td>Shipping</td><!---Want to show shipping custom label here -->
</tr><tr><td><strike>₹80</strike><?= _"FREE"; ?></td><!---shipping value -->
</tr><tr><td>Subtotal</td><!---Default show specail price -->
</tr><tr><td><?= _$specialprice; ?></td><!---Default special price value -->
</tr><tr><td>Tax</td><!---Default -->
</tr><tr><td><?= _$tax; ?></td><!---Default tax value -->
</tr>        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How we do this in magento2 please help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `abstract-total.js` to make this happen using a RequireJs mixin. This way you can extend a JavaScript object provided by Magento and only add your own adjustments:

In `view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/abstract-total-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

In `view/frontend/web/js/abstract-total-mixin.js`:

```
define([], function () {
    "use strict";

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend({
            /**
             * @return {*}
             */
            isFullMode: function () {
                if (!this.getTotals()) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Reference: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/235329/56248

Comment: dear sir will please help me to achieve my labels in cart page summary. Actually I am new in magento2 and need explanation for this. Please...

Comment: sure, what question do you have?

Comment: Please help with code and files so we can achieve all of these on cart page. I want to display regular price, special price, shipping with strike, discount of special price, then tax on cart page, please help dear @Wolfack.

Comment: please try the solution I added in this answer, that'll surely help, if it doesn't work let me know

Comment: it's not working dear. I have tested on my staging website as per you prescribed the steps above see the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1iydwrb

Please help!